# jekyll not generating index.html

Tags: jekyll

I have been using Jekyll for my blog and it has been working fine. Now I am trying to add new posts from a computer running Ubuntu 14.04 and Jekyll 2.4.0. The problem is that, only on this computer, it does not generate index.html in _site.

I can't find anything in the documentation that helps, and in any event, I'm using git so I have the same configuration on all of my machines.

So the question is: **How does one turn off generation of index.html in Jekyll, and how can it be turned back on?**

[Update: I did `gem uninstall jekyll` followed by `gem install jekyll`, rebuilt the site, and everything works fine. The original install must not have completed properly.]

Comment: A repository url can be very helpful to debug.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Unfortunately it is a private Git server, not Github or Bitbucket, so I don't have a way to link to it.

Comment: No code, no debug ;-) Check your _config/exclude, file permissions and file encoding (utf-8)

Comment: @user2225804 I had the same problem and reinstalling jekyll fixed it. I had 2 versions of jekyll somehow.

Answer (score 0):

To turn generation off you can remove this file. Or to use static index.html file remove markdown section enclosed with double triple `---` in header (in this case static index.html will be parsed). Also mention filename it in `exclude:` section of `_config.yml` to avoid copying to `_site` folder.